# Authentication with Google App Engine service using GoogleCredential with a Service Account

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-oauth, google-client-login

I have a GAE application with an endpoint that requires authentication, which I call from an application (rather than from in a browser).

Here is the GAE specification of the endpoints from web.xml

```
<!-- Secure sensitive URLs -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/gcm/home</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/gcm/send</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Previously, in the client application, I was using ClientLogin to authenticate with Google before calling the endpoint. This is the code I was using, that extracts the "Auth" token which it then uses as a Cookie on HTTP GET to the above endpoints.

```
public static String loginToGoogle(String userid, String password,        
        String appUrl) throws Exception {        
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();        
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(        
            "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");        

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();        
    reqEntity.addPart("accountType", new StringBody("HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",        
            "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));        
    reqEntity.addPart("Email", new StringBody(userid));        
    reqEntity.addPart("Passwd", new StringBody(password));        
    reqEntity.addPart("service", new StringBody("ah"));        
    reqEntity.addPart("source", new StringBody("WWWWmyappname"));        
    post.setEntity(reqEntity);        
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);        
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {        
        InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();        
        String result = IOUtils.toString(input);        
        String authToken = getAuthToken(result);        
        post = new HttpPost(appUrl + "/_ah/login?auth=" + authToken);        
        response = client.execute(post);        
        Header[] cookies = response.getHeaders("SET-COOKIE");        
        for (Header cookie : cookies) {        
            if (cookie.getValue().startsWith("ACSID=")) {        
                return cookie.getValue();        
            }        
        }        
        throw new Exception("ACSID cookie cannot be found");        
    } else        
        throw new Exception("Error obtaining ACSID");        
}        

private static String getAuthToken(String responseText) throws Exception {        
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(        
            responseText));        
    String line = reader.readLine();        
    while (line != null) {        
        line = line.trim();        
        if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {        
            return line.substring(5);        
        }        
        line = reader.readLine();        
    }        
    throw new Exception("Could not find Auth token");        
}
```

Since ClientLogin was deprecated and then removed, I believe I am obliged to switch to OAuth2. Reading the documentation led me to believe I needed a Service Account for this purpose, which I duly set up in the Google Console for the GAE.
Although the GoogleCredential builder successfully returns an authorization token, if I then use that token in an HTTP get call to the endpoint, the response is always the Google Login page.

Why, if I use the token, does GAE not think I am logged in and authorized? Am I doing this all wrong or missing a step?

Here is the code that tries to authenticate with Google and then call the GAE endpoint:

```
    String emailAddress = "XXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    String emailScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    String keyFileName = "YYYYY.p12";
    String baseURL = "http://ZZZZZ.appspot.com";
    HttpTransport httpTransport;
    try {
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        File keyFile = new File(keyFileName);
        if(!keyFile.exists()) {
            System.err.println("Key file "+keyFileName+" missing");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(emailScope))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(keyFile)
        .build();

        boolean success = credential.refreshToken();
        System.out.println("Access token refresh "+ success);

        String token = credential.getAccessToken();

        System.out.println("Token "+token);

        String uri = "http://ZZZZZ.appspot.com/gcm/home";

        System.out.println("uri: " + uri);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        get.setHeader("Cookie", token);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);
```

Typical output:

```
   Access token refresh true
   Token ya29.xQGG1kxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   uri: http://ZZZZZ.appspot.com/gcm/home

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
      <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
      <title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>
      .....
```

Thanks!

Comment: is your application server application which wont be distributed to many users? If so, you can use client_secrets.json instead of GoogleCredential. Let me know if thats the case, i can answer with the code sample

Comment: Hi Sriram, Yes! This application runs in a single instance on a secure server, and is not intended for users. What it does is acquire messages from ActiveMQ and forward them to GAE for distribution to Android phones using Google Cloud Messaging. I'd welcome a code sample for client_secrets!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

Comment: Hi Sriram, thanks for that pointer, which is focused on the Drive API, which I am not using in my GAE application. I've edited my question to give more details about what I am doing, as it wasn't as clear as it could have been.